# antd prepopulate tags and multi select

Tags: antd

I'm working on antd select and having issues with prepopulating it correctly, I can prepopulate the select box via its initialValue field decorator, however it populates strings, there does not appear to be a way to have a value (something I can work around but not ideal), and more importantly if the option is unselected/removed, it is no longer available in the select, unlike standard options. I can include in both select list options and initial value (as demonstrated in code below) but then it allows duplicate auto entry and it appears twice in the drop down list. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Preperation of Preselected and Full Option List

```
    let defaultSelect = [];
    let selectList = [];
    for (var a = 0; a < this.props.myData.length; a++) {
        //push all options to select list
        selectList.push(<Select.Option key={this.props.myData[i].id} >{this.props.myData[i].name}</Select.Option>)
        //this is my code to pre-populate options, by performing a find/match
        let matchedTech = _.find(this.props.myDataPrepopulate, { id: this.props.myData[i].id });
        if (matchedTech) {
            //notice I can push just the string name, not the name and the id value.
            defaultSelect.push(this.props.myData[i].name);
        }
    }
```

Select Code

```
    {getFieldDecorator(row.name, {
        initialValue: defaultSelect
    })(
    <Select
        tags
        notFoundContent='none found'
        filterOption={(input, option) => option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}
        {selectList}
    </Select>
    )}
```

Comment: Your posted code has many syntax errors: i is undefined, <Select tag unclosed etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question, even if you posted code that doesn't run.

`<Select.Option>` works just like the plain html `<select><option/></select>`. In order to give the option a value it needs a `value` attribute, which is used to identify the option.

See http://codepen.io/JesperWe/pen/YVqBor for a working example.

The crucial part transformed to your example would become:

```
this.props.myData.forEach( data => {
    selectList.push(<Select.Option value={data.id} key={data.id}>{data.name}</Select.Option>);
} );

defaultSelect = this.props.myDataPrepopulate.map( data => data.id );
```

(I took the liberty to use a bit more modern code patterns than your original)